# How to run chromedriver using Selenium (Windows 10)?

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am attempting to automate a web browser using the environment below:

Windows10, Selenium (v3.141.0), Python (v3.7.4) chrome (v77.0.3865.90), and chromedriver (v77.0.3865.40). I installed pip, installed Selenium(using Python), set my paths in the environmental variables, called out the path to my chromedriver, and I still am running into issues.

-path using for chromedriver: "C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe"
-path to Python: "C:\Users\linds\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37"

I have some code that I ran below with errors. Any ideas?

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
>>> options = Options()
>>> options.add_argument('--headless')
>>> options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
>>> options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#31>", line 1, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  File "C:\Users\linds\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\linds\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\linds\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\linds\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\linds\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create a Chrome process.
```

Comment: I'd be very interested in a solution to this. I had to switch to Python and selenium due to this same problem.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what the latest chrome and chromedriver and windows combinations are that work for people. Related but not a solution in my case at least: https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/issues/158

Comment: Can you help me updating the question with the complete error stacktrace with Chrome?

Comment: Try turning off all antivirus/firewall/windows defender. Also try `chromedriver --verbose` from cmd.exe

Comment: @pguardiario Don't know if same for op but running chromedriver --verbose for me leaving cmd hanging after saying _Starting ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed._  Admittedly, I have an earlier chromedriver but with windows 10.  I have no problem running python with selenium on same machine.

Comment: @Qharr - that's what it's supposed to do. It's waiting for connections.

Comment: @QHarr I thought the issue was related to Selenium, the chromedriver, and the OS, meaning VBA is independent. What OS are you using with Python/Selenium?

Comment: I am running Windows 10. No problem at all with python.

Comment: @QHarr, gotcha. I stated that I get an error when running driver directly from the Selenium VB script. You must not get this error?

Comment: I’m saying if I run in vba I get same error as you. If I run from python no problem.

Comment: @QHarr I am moving forward with python. I updated the OP with the error codes I am getting now. Any ideas?

Comment: @DebanjanB would be the ideal person to help now

Comment: @DebanjanB is the updated post with the errors helpful?

Comment: @Average_VBAer As of the current version, your question is too broad. There is `MicrosoftEdge`, `Chrome 77.0`, `VB script`, `VBA code`, `chromedriver=77.0` and `Python`. If you can reduce the scope of the question I will take a second look.

Comment: @DebanjanB I updated the post. Hopefully this is what you need. Thanks!